# how to adjust rigidbody settings for lots of objects

Tags: python, rigidbody

I got a scene width lots of small objects (around 2000 icospheres).
I need to be able adjust rigid body settings for all those 2000 icospheres
Any idea on how to do that (perhaps by the use of python, but how ?)

Answer (score 2):

Well it was easier then i thought it would be.
I created one example object and named it LikeMe, there i set all rigid body options. Then since all target objects have similair names (alls starting width Icosphere added a * at the end and did a select pattern, finalized width a copy of rigid body settings

```
import bpy
scene = bpy.context.scene
scene.objects.active = bpy.data.objects["LikeMe"]
bpy.ops.object.select_pattern(pattern="Icosphere*", case_sensitive=True)
bpy.ops.rigidbody.object_settings_copy()
```

Comment: The `object_settings_copy` that does the work is already easily available in the toolshelf. You can find it in the Physics tab "Copy From Active" button.

Answer (score 1):

Glad you found a solution on your own, there's one more way to do it that does not require coding.
Just select all the rigidbodies you have, making sure **source object is selected last** (so it is set as active).
Now press **Space** and start typing in "**Copy Rigid Body Settings**".